# ValueError: `f0` passed has more than 1 dimension

Tags: numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Dimension error appears when trying to call minimize function

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import minimize, line_search

x1=[1,2,1] ; y1=0
x2=[1,1,2] ; y2=0
x3=[2,3,3] ; y3=1
x4=[2,2,1] ; y4=1
x5=[1,2,3] ; y5=0
x6=[1,3,1] ; y6=1
x7=[1,1,1] ; y7=0
x8=[1,2,2] ; y8=0
x9=[1,2,1] ; y9=0
x10=[1,1,1] ; y10=0
x11=[2,2,2] ; y11=1
x12=[1,2,2] ; y12=0

X= np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12])
y=np.array([y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10,y11,y12])
n=len(y)

def h(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
def r(beta):
    f=0
    for i in range(n):
        f=f+ (1-y[i])* np.dot(X[i],beta) + np.log( 1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],beta)  ))
    return np.array([f/n])

#gradient of r
def gradr(beta):
    f=0
    for i in range(n):
        mu= h(np.dot(X[i],beta))
        f=f+ (mu-y[i])*X[i]
    return (f/n).reshape(3,1)

def exactsearch(beta_0,d):
    phi_aux = lambda alfa : r(beta_0+ alfa*d)
    alfa_0=np.array([1])
    bds=[(0,None)]
    res =  minimize(phi_aux, alfa_0, bounds=bds)
    alfa=np.array([res.x])
    return alfa

def GradientMethod(beta,f):
    N=0
    e=10**(-5)
    p=-gradr(beta)
    alfa=f(beta,p)
    while True:
        if r(beta)==r(beta+alfa*p):break 
        if N==10000:break
        if alfa<=e:break
        else:
            N=N+1
            beta=beta+alfa*p
            p=-gradr(beta)
            alfa=f(beta,p)
    return [beta,r(beta),N]

GradientMethod(np.array([1,1,1]),exactsearch)
```

`X` is a 3 by 12 matrix, `r` is a function that takes a size 3 vector and operates it with the vectors of `X`

When changing `np.exp` to `math.exp` the error changes to `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. Also, previously I encountered the error `ValueError: shapes (3,) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)` but it went away when reshaping `gradr`.

I must add that I don't understand that much the function `exactsearch`, since it was given to me.

Full error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-bb9e6dc26271> in <module>
     62     return [beta,r(beta),N]
     63 
---> 64 GradientMethod(np.array([1,1,1]),exactsearch)

<ipython-input-20-bb9e6dc26271> in GradientMethod(beta, f)
     50     e=10**(-5)
     51     p=-gradr(beta)
---> 52     alfa=f(beta,p)
     53     while True:
     54         if r(beta)==r(beta+alfa*p):break

<ipython-input-20-bb9e6dc26271> in exactsearch(beta_0, d)
     42     alfa_0=np.array([1])
     43     bds=[(0,None)]
---> 44     res =  minimize(phi_aux, alfa_0, bounds=bds)
     45     alfa=np.array([res.x])
     46     return alfa

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    615                                   **options)
    616     elif meth == 'l-bfgs-b':
--> 617         return _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
    618                                 callback=callback, **options)
    619     elif meth == 'tnc':

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py in _minimize_lbfgsb(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds, disp, maxcor, ftol, gtol, eps, maxfun, maxiter, iprint, callback, maxls, finite_diff_rel_step, **unknown_options)
    304             iprint = disp
    305 
--> 306     sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
    307                                   bounds=new_bounds,
    308                                   finite_diff_rel_step=finite_diff_rel_step)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args, bounds, epsilon, finite_diff_rel_step, hess)
    259     # ScalarFunction caches. Reuse of fun(x) during grad
    260     # calculation reduces overall function evaluations.
--> 261     sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
    262                         finite_diff_rel_step, bounds, epsilon=epsilon)
    263 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py in __init__(self, fun, x0, args, grad, hess, finite_diff_rel_step, finite_diff_bounds, epsilon)
     93 
     94         self._update_grad_impl = update_grad
---> 95         self._update_grad()
     96 
     97         # Hessian Evaluation

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py in _update_grad(self)
    169     def _update_grad(self):
    170         if not self.g_updated:
--> 171             self._update_grad_impl()
    172             self.g_updated = True
    173 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py in update_grad()
     89                 self._update_fun()
     90                 self.ngev += 1
---> 91                 self.g = approx_derivative(fun_wrapped, self.x, f0=self.f,
     92                                            **finite_diff_options)
     93 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_numdiff.py in approx_derivative(fun, x0, method, rel_step, abs_step, f0, bounds, sparsity, as_linear_operator, args, kwargs)
    386         f0 = np.atleast_1d(f0)
    387         if f0.ndim > 1:
--> 388             raise ValueError("`f0` passed has more than 1 dimension.")
    389 
    390     if np.any((x0 < lb) | (x0 > ub)):

ValueError: `f0` passed has more than 1 dimension.
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the problem was with the dimensions of the arrays, somewhere for some reason an array went from being like `[1,2,3]` to `[[1,2,3]]`, changing its shape from (3,) to (1,3), I tried to fix it by reshaping `gradr` to (3,1) but this just made everything worse, instead the solution was to eliminate the reshape of `gradr` and reshape every beta to (3,) before its operated.

```
def r(beta):
    f=0
    beta=beta.reshape(3,)
    for i in range(n):
        f=f+ (1-y[i])* np.dot(X[i],beta) + np.log( 1+np.exp(-np.dot(X[i],beta)  ))
    return np.array([f/n])

#gradient of r
def gradr(beta):
    f=0
    beta=beta.reshape(3,)
    for i in range(n):
        mu= h(np.dot(X[i],beta))
        f=f+ (mu-y[i])*X[i]
    return (f/n)
```